# Definition making center of mass irrotational

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, mass

In a body of mass $m$, we define the center of mass to be a point such that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{N}m_j\vec{r}_{CM,j}=\vec{0}$$

where $\vec{r}_{CM,j}$ is the distance of the particle $m_j$ from the center of mass. Again, in handwavy terms, we are taught that if an object is going through a combination of motions, the center of mass always goes one motion. So, how do we derive this fact from the *mathematical definition* which is exactly how center of mass is defined?

I mean to say, suppose an object is doing a transrotational motion. We find a point from the mathematical expression above. Now, why will that point (a.k.a. center of mass) be the point that is doing the *translational motion*?

Comment: "Now, why will that point(a.k.a center of mass) be the point that is doing the translational motion?" A point is dimensionless.  There is nothing to rotate.

Comment: @BobD thank you for replying. I actually wanted to know why will it only be the center of mass point that will do linear motion. Why does it's mathematical expression differentiate it from other ordinary points that those ordinary points do circular motion but the center of mass doesn't.

Comment: @brendandarrer with due respect: what a useless edit…. you did not improve the post in any substantive way, just inserted some spaces.  Really…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, thanks for your feedback. Yes, there wasn't much to change here except some grammatical spaces and a full stop. You're probably right, I should have left as it was! I take your point.

Comment: The center of mass can execute circular motion. The reason why it’s a useful point for problem solving is because there are numerous theorems that help reduce a problem to its motion. Check out the center of mass theorem and Konig’s theorems.

Comment: @madness What makes you think only the COM will do linear motion?